# Receive File in server action

Tags: typescript, next.js, next.js13, react-server-components, server-action

I have an application built with `NextJS` 14. I'm trying to take advantage of server actions, using it in a simple form that receives two files and return one.

Is this possible with server actions? I have the code, but when I try to return the file, it throws an error.

This is my code:

> CMSForm.tsx

```js
export default function CMSForm() {
    const t = useTranslations('tools.cms')
    const initialState: State = { message: null, errors: {} }
    const [state, dispatch] = useFormState(transformExcel, initialState)

    return (
        <form
            action={dispatch}
            className='flex flex-col justify-center p-4 gap-4 border rounded bg-white dark:bg-zinc-900/50'
        >
            <fieldset className='flex gap-4 items-start justify-center'>
                <div className='flex flex-col'>
                    <label htmlFor='file' className='font-semibold'>
                        {t('fileToUpload')}
                    </label>
                    <FileInput
                        type='file'
                        id='file'
                        name='file'
                        className='p-2'
                        aria-describedby='file-error'
                        accept='application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'
                    />
                    <div id='customer-error' aria-live='polite' aria-atomic='true'>
                        {state?.errors?.file &&
                            state.errors.file.map((error: string) => (
                                <p className='mt-2 text-sm text-red-500' key={error}>
                                    {error}
                                </p>
                            ))}
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className='flex flex-col'>
                    <label htmlFor='template' className='font-semibold'>
                        {t('outputTemplate')}
                    </label>
                    <FileInput
                        type='file'
                        id='template'
                        name='template'
                        className='p-2'
                        aria-describedby='template-error'
                        accept='application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'
                    />
                    <div id='customer-error' aria-live='polite' aria-atomic='true'>
                        {state?.errors?.template &&
                            state.errors.template.map((error: string) => (
                                <p className='mt-2 text-sm text-red-500' key={error}>
                                    {error}
                                </p>
                            ))}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </fieldset>
            <Button type='submit' colorScheme='blue' className=' w-56 mx-auto'>
                {t('convertToCMS')}
            </Button>
        </form>
    )
}
```

And the action:

```js
'use server'
import { z } from 'zod'
import { generateCMSFile } from './CMSExcelService'

const MAX_FILE_SIZE = 5000000
const ACCEPTED_FILE_TYPE = 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'

const TextExtractionSchema = z.object({
    file: z
        .instanceof(File)
        .refine((file) => file?.size <= MAX_FILE_SIZE, {
            message: 'Please upload a file smaller than 5MB.'
        })
        .refine((file) => file.type === ACCEPTED_FILE_TYPE, {
            message: 'Only .xlsx format are supported.'
        }),
    template: z
        .instanceof(File)
        .refine((file) => file?.size <= MAX_FILE_SIZE, {
            message: 'Please upload a file smaller than 5MB.'
        })
        .refine((file) => file.type === ACCEPTED_FILE_TYPE, {
            message: 'Only .xlsx format are supported.'
        })
})

export type State = {
    errors?: {
        file?: string[]
        template?: string[]
    }
    message?: string | null
}
export async function transformExcel(_prevState: State | undefined, formData: FormData) {
    const validatedFields = TextExtractionSchema.safeParse({
        file: formData.get('file'),
        template: formData.get('template')
    })
    if (!validatedFields.success) {
        return {
            errors: validatedFields.error.flatten().fieldErrors,
            message: 'Missing Fields. Failed to Create Invoice.'
        }
    }

    const { file, template } = validatedFields.data

    try {
        const transformedFile = await generateCMSFile({ excel: file, template })
        const fileName = transformedFile.headers['content-disposition']?.split('filename=')[1]

        const downloadFile = new Blob([transformedFile.data])


        // HERE IS WHERE I SHOULD SEND THE FILE
    } catch (error) {
        return {
            message: 'Failed to transform excel file.'
        }
    }
}
```

The error that I receive is
`Error: Only plain objects, and a few built-ins, can be passed to Client Components from Server Components. Classes or null prototypes are not supported`

I'm not sure if server actions can support this approach. The alternative is using an Route handler and then manage the download in the client component.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks for reading

Comment: Did you get any further with a solution for this? It looks like route handlers is the next best option

Comment: Not for the moment. I'm going with route handlers :(